# From long to wide format with the same duplicates

Tags: r, dplyr, quanteda

Trying this command:

```
library("spacyr")
library("dplyr", warn.conflicts = FALSE)

mytext <- data.frame(text = c("test text", "section 2 sending"), 
                     id = c(32,41))
df2 <- tidyr::separate_rows(mytext, text)

df3 <- data.frame(text = df2$text, id = df2$id)

dflemma <- spacy_parse(structure(df3$text, names = df3$id),
                       lemma = TRUE, pos = FALSE)  %>%
    mutate(id = doc_id) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    summarize(body = paste(lemma, collapse = " "))
```

the expected output is the long to wide format using the same id and separate the merge text with a space. Here the expected output

```
data.frame(text = c("test text", "section 2 send"), 
                     id = c(32,41)
```

However the command provide this error:

```
Error in process_document(x, multithread) : Docnames are duplicated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because you separate each of your text phrases to words. You shouldn't do that. Consider the following code:

```
mytext <- data.frame(text = c("test text", "section 2 sending"), id = c(32,41))
dflemma <- 
  spacy_parse(structure(mytext$text, names = mytext$id), lemma = TRUE, pos = FALSE) %>% 
  group_by(id = doc_id) %>% 
  summarise(text = paste(lemma, collapse = " "))
```

Output

```
> dflemma
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  id    text          
  <chr> <chr>         
1 32    test text     
2 41    section 2 send
```

**Update**

If you have to do the separation, then you need to further modify your `id` column to ensure that each observation in it is unique. Later you can change those `id`s back at the `group_by` stage. Consider the following code.

```
mytext <- data.frame(text = c("test text", "section 2 sending"), id = c(32,41))
df2 <- tidyr::separate_rows(mytext, text) %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(id = paste0(id, "-", seq_len(n())))
dflemma <- 
  spacy_parse(structure(df2$text, names = df2$id), lemma = TRUE, pos = FALSE) %>% 
  group_by(id = sub("(.+)-(.+)", "\\1", doc_id)) %>% 
  summarise(text = paste(lemma, collapse = " "))
```

Comment: thank you I new the separation first because there are some words that are not treated as lemmazation as I expect

Comment: Hi, I hope the updated code could solve your problem. @demia

Answer (score 2):

Try this `base R` solution on your `df3`:

```
#Code
dflemma <- aggregate(text~id,df3,function(x) paste(x,collapse = ' '))
```

Output:

```
  id              text
1 32         test text
2 41 section 2 sending
```

Comment: thank you. The output of spacy_parse is different so I would like to make in this command